# How to set the vpc of a db instance when I create one via boto3's 'rds.create_db_instance'?

Tags: amazon-rds, boto3

When I create a mysql db via AWS console, I can control to which VPC the db instance lands.

[image]

However when i tried to use boto3 `rds.create_db_instance` to create a mysql db, the option is not available. At least I cannot see any `VpcId` parameter.

How can I set this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide *--db-subnet-group-name* with *rds.create_db_instance*, it should use the vpc id from subnet group.

Comment: My question is more about `boto3`, but the idea is right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create something called a subnet group. This can be done with the same boto3 client via the [create_db_subnet_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_subnet_group) method. Use the name of the subnet group for the `DBSubnetGroupName` parameter on the `create_db_instance` method.